# Java : How to set the flag value in a array loop

Tags: java

This is my below mehod for Validation .

```
public boolean validateData(Bagform[] bagdata) {
    boolean flag = false;
    int length = bagdata.length;

    if (length == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bagdata.length; i++) {
            if (bagdata[i].getCallType() == null) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

In this basically i am checking that if the getCallType()  is not  null for any of the values in the array .

If its not null , then its a valid data , so i am setting the flag to true .
(Please see the code above )

But for me , i am getting the  flag value still  as false  ( Even though the getCallype() is not null )

Please help me .

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is very awkward to read.

Comment: **flag** is a poor variable name.  How about **isValid** instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the flag to true if the call type *is* null. I suspect you want:

```
public boolean validateData(Bagform[] bagdata) {
    boolean flag = true;
    int length = bagdata.length;

    if (length == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bagdata.length; i++) {
            if (bagdata[i].getCallType() == null) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

It's not clear why you're only performing this validation when there are exactly two entries in the array though. Unless that's really deliberate, I'd have written this has:

```
public boolean validateData(Bagform[] bagdata) {
    for (Bagform form : bagdata) {
        if (form.getCallType() == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , you saved my day , and your coding style is also good .